# Is the final history object of sequential model.fit() calls accurate?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have several seperate training datasets that when read as one crash the kernel in jupyter. So I did a workaround and read them separately in a sequence and call fit() on the same model-object.

To get accuracy metrics I am only grabbing the final history-object, but does this also represent all previous fit()-calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `history` is initialized as a callback every time anew when you call fit. This is unless you provide some alternative. One way to do so is to pass the model's `history` from one `fit()` call to the next `fit()` as a callback:

```
model.fit(x, y, batch_size, epochs, callbacks=[model.history])
```

this way the new values will be appended to the previously accumulated values, so you'd get statistics over multiple runs of `fit()`.

If you need something more special - save and process `history` objects  from each fit or write a custom callback with memory.

Comment: Results look reasonable. Though couldn't find that in keras documentary. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it is in the source code for model.fit() (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1048-L1056). If no callbacks are provided - a new callback list including `history` is initialized.